how to add hyperlinks in a pdf using openedge
I need to know if there is a way to add a hyperlink to a PDF using the OpenEdge PDF include libraries
I couldn't find anything on the internet about this topic, if anyone has an example they can show me I would appreciate it.

I am going to assume that you are using the PDFInclude libraries that are popular with Progress.
RUN pdf_link ("Spdf", 100, 100, 300, 300,
 "https://example.com",
 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1, "I").

Refer to the official documtentation for a complete explanation (page 85). Different versions might have slightly different parameters but this should help out at least:
https://www.snowwolf-software.com/pdfinclude/readme.pdf
